# How can I find where one word is close to another word?

Tags: regular-expression, search

If I want to find occurrences of the word 'arc', I can type `/ arc` , with spaces around the three letters, to find basic occurrences of the word (ignoring punctuation). But suppose I want to find where two words are close together, say, within ten words? Here's an example:

> Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.

In this test, I want to find all occurrences where the word 'aid' is within ten words of the word 'country'. How can I do that in Vim?

Comment: Also, instead of spaces you can use word boundaries: `/\<arc\>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find `aid` separated from `country` by at most 3 words, choose one:

- ```
  /aid\(\W\+\w\+\)\{,3}\W\+country
  ```
- ```
  /\vaid(\W+\w+){,3}\W+country
  ```

If words may be separated only by single space characters, it can be further simplified to

- ```
  /\vaid( \w+){,3} country
  ```

---

Try it on this minimal, reproducible example:

```
Now is to the aid of their country.
Now aid of come their the country.
```

Only the first line should have a match, as it contains 2 words between `aid` and `country`, while the second line contains 4 words between `aid` and `country`.

---

The [regex elements](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html) explained:

- `(\W+\w+)` = a capture group, capturing `\W+\w+`.

  - `\W+\w+` = 1 or more non-word characters followed by 1 or more word characters.
- `{,3}` = The maximum number of occurrences of the capture group.

The very magic mode is enabled with a leading `\v`, so as to get rid of so much escaping in the non-magic counterpart.

Comment: BTW, why `\W` (non-word) instead of `\s` (whitespace). With the former, a distance of three, and target words "SS" and "EE" you'd get three matches in `SS The quick brown EE fox jumped SS over twenty-two EE dogs at SS 3:12:20 EE last Thursday.`. That looks like three, two and one word between SS/EE respectively. If you wanted the number and time to count as single words you'd want to replace `\W` with `\s` and `\w` with `\S`. Then this would have three matches: `SS The quick brown EE fox jumped SS over twenty-two dogs EE at SS 3:12:20 last Thursday EE.`

Comment: @BLayer Indeed, that is relevant. The definition of word in the "regex world" is `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, but linguistically twenty-two may be counted as a single word. I went for the first definition.

Comment: There is no standard definition of "word" in regex land. And twenty-two _is_ one word. The hyphen makes it so. Anyways, my goal was just to raise the issue for others to be aware of it rather than change anyone's mind.

Comment: @BLayer In the "POSIX standard" sense, there is not, but [it is the most common](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes). I'm sure your goal is just to point out something relevant (it is!), but I cannot lose the chance to exchange ideas with the community :)